# Github makes a repo of documents folder

Tags: github

My Github decided to make a repo of my whole "Documents" folder. Is there a way to disable it, because it's really annoying when working with that folder?

Comment: create a folder and `initialize` github repo there

Comment: and there is no way to "un-repo" the entire folder?

Comment: You can just `move` all `directories` and `files` related to `git` to a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `.git` folder within Documents to remove the Git repository.